# Find the maximum and minimum of $(1/x-1)(1/y-1)(1/z-1)$ if $x+y+z=1$

Tags: inequality, lagrange-multiplier

I get more confused when I try to solve this. For my first approach, I'm using normal AM-GM inequality:
\begin{equation}
  (\frac{1}{x}-1)(\frac{1}{y}-1)(\frac{1}{z}-1)=\frac{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}{xyz} \\=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}-1
\end{equation}
By $x+y+z=1\geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}$ $\Rightarrow \frac{1}{27} \geq xyz$ we get
\begin{equation}
  (\frac{1}{x}-1)(\frac{1}{y}-1)(\frac{1}{z}-1)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}-1\geq 8
\end{equation}
So this is the minimum value. I do some research for how to find the maximum and come across an interesting Theorem " Lagrange Multipliers " than I'm using this to solve the problem. I'm not pretty good at Latex so I'm going for a shortcut. So we have $f(x,y,z)= (\frac{1}{x}-1)(\frac{1}{y}-1)(\frac{1}{z}-1)$ and $g(x)=x+y+z-1$. After derivated I get:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{-1+z+y-yz}{x^2yz}=\frac{-1+x+z-xz}{xy^2z}=\frac{-1+x+y-xy}{xyz^2}=\lambda
\end{equation}
Solving this I get $x=y=1$, $z=-1$ and so on...this kind of solution give 0 for the answer. And $x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$ which give 8. But that mean 8 is the maximum!? Please help

Comment: Are there other constraints?  As stated, the function has neither globally minimizing nor globally maximizing points.  By taking $y,z:=\dfrac{1-x}{2}$, you can show that the function can be arbitrarily large both positively and negatively.  If $x,y,z>0$ holds, then a simple AM-GM argument shows that the unique maximizing point is given by $x=y=z=\dfrac13$.

Comment: Isn't that give $x=0$?

Comment: I dun include the case where $x,y,z$ equal 0

Comment: In my comment above, I made a typo.  The last sentence should be "If $x,y,z>0$ holds, then a simple AM-GM argument shows that the unique ***minimizing*** point is given by $x=y=z=\dfrac13$."  Using [Shubhrajit Bhattacharya's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3720963/72152) below with a small $\epsilon<0$, you can show that your function has no globally minimizing points if you don't have the constraint $x,y,z>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the expression $$\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{y}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{z}-1\right)$$ can be made arbitrarily large with the constraint $(x+y+z)=1$

**Proof:** Let $N>0$ be any arbitrary large real number. Choose $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ such that $$\frac{1}{\varepsilon}>(N+1)$$ Then let $x=\varepsilon,y=z=\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2}$. Then clearly $$x,y,z>0,(x+y+z)=1\quad\text{and}\quad\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{y}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{z}-1\right)=\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1\right)\left(\frac{2}{1-\varepsilon}-1\right)^2>\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1\right)(2-1)^2=\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1\right)>N$$ $$\tag*{$\left[\text{since $\frac{2}{1-\varepsilon}>2$}\right]$}$$

Hence the expression $$\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{y}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{z}-1\right)$$
can be made arbitrarily large and hence attains no maximum in the set $$\mathcal{S}=\{(x,y,z):x,y,z>0;(x+y+z)=1\}$$ So $$\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{y}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{z}-1\right)\in[8,\infty)\;\forall\;(x,y,z)\in\mathcal{S}$$

$\tag*{$\square$}$

Comment: not related to the solve, but I'm wondering how do you justify the text inside [ ] on the right like this ?

Comment: Here is the TeX command `\tag*{$\left[\text{since $\frac{2}{1-\varepsilon}>2$}\right]$}`